# WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Tags: java, spring, rest, tomcat

I am just started to implement simple Spring REST api application. My web.xml file looks like as following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">


<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

And this is my dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.suntravel.service.controller" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And here is my SunTravelController.java class.

```
package com.suntravel.service.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/suntravel")
public class SunTravelController
{
 @RequestMapping(value = "/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public String getHotelList( @PathVariable String name )
{
    return name;

}

}
```

Then I deployed this in tomcat server and trying to access http://localhost:8080/SpringRestServer/suntravel?Bob

Then I am getting following error in my console log.

```
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringRestServer/suntravel] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

Project Structure

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a Bob.jsp in web-inf?  If so, I think you mean for your url to be http://localhost:8080/SpringRestServer/suntravle/bob

Comment: Here use Bob as a requested parameter

Comment: do you have any .jsp files in web-inf?

Comment: yes,idex,jsp. If I  try http://localhost:8080/SpringRestServer/ then it loads index.jsp page

Comment: make a copy of index.jsp, call it blah.jsp, and modify it a bit, so that you can tell the difference between index and blah.  then start your server, and point a browser at http://localhost:8080/SpringRestServer/blah, and let me know if you see the blah.jsp or not.

Comment: It gives **WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringRestServer/blah] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'**

Answer (score 0):

You need to unclude the `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` element in your application context config.This registers beans to handle your annotated controllers.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.suntravel.service.controller" />

<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Also when accessing your service use `/Bob` and not  `?Bob` as you are using `@PathVariable` and not `@RequestParam`

```
 http://localhost:8080/SpringRestServer/suntravel?Bob    < wrong
 http://localhost:8080/SpringRestServer/suntravel/Bob    < right
```

Comment: what is mvc:annotation-driven element ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

        <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

        <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
        <annotation-driven />

        <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
            <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </beans:bean>

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.suntravel.service.controller" />



    </beans:beans>
```

Comment: then what will happen to dispatcher-servlet

Comment: my bad!! this is the new dispatcher-servlet.xml. Updated the post

Comment: Tried. but same warning is coming

Comment: Created a MVC project. Tried to keep the file names same as yours: https://github.com/shaimakh/stackoverflow.